# How to Check the Remaining Number of Votes?

Tags: support, voting

Is there a way to check the remaining number of votes available for the day on SO?

I know SO gives a popup showing the number of remaining votes when you are nearing the daily limit. But is there a way to know this beforehand?

Comment: Also on Meta.SE: [Reliable count of votes that I've cast today](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239601)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also go on to your profile page, and go under votes cast which is in the activity section.

[image: Votes Cast]

I'm not entirely sure how often it updates (or whether it's real time), but this is the way of figuring that out.

Comment: It's fuzzy at best; I don't think it takes deleted questions/answers into account.

Comment: Yes, I was about to add this as my own answer. I did a couple of experiments. Unlike the answer in a link provided by @Anthon, the daily count stays visible all the time. The daily maximum now is 40 and one can see how much he has used up. As for the update frequency, it's not real time.

Comment: It updates with a lag of on the order of an hour or two, in my limited experience. Not real-time, but you can usually use it in practice as long as you stretch your votes out a bit.

Answer (score 7):

There is not. This has been asked  [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/display-the-number-of-votes-a-user-has-left-for-the-day) (and answered by Jeff Atwood) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186767/how-to-find-the-number-of-comment-votes-remaining-today)

Comment: The link you provided is around 2years old. Things have changed since then, like the daily limit being 40 now. The accepted answer in your first link says: "once you get below (n) votes the count is displayed" &
"above (n) votes the count is not displayed". I'm going to explore and experiment a bit more to see if that is still around... Will accept in a while.

Comment: @kRiZ Actually the first one is almost six years old. But I would hope that Jeff would update his answer if the policy changes, and if not, I would still assume someone commenting if it changed and he had not updated.

Comment: You're right. My bad, I was looking at the "active' section.

Comment: @Anthon You want somebody with >4000 answers to remember every one and update them if they become slightly outdated?

Comment: @Dason Really all it takes is someone to post a comment requesting an update. I've done it a few times before

Comment: I think a warning at 10 votes left would be nicer.